# SSAS cubes not displaying data for new codes created

Tags: ssas, axapta, olap-cube

Good day,

There has been new stock codes created on our Dynamics AX, I can see there has been transactions on this, but the data is not displayed on the sales cube. I can see the item ID in the list but there are no values.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to process or update your cubes. This isn't a programming question though so I'm going to vote close.  Here are some resources to help though:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc618242.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd309611(v=ax.50).aspx